# how to pass youtube api auth and permission response from server to client's webrowser

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, youtube, youtube-api

So I have a Python script that is being run on the server (PHP runs it). However, script has to authenticate user on youtube. When you run it localy it opens the browser, allows to authenticate and asks for permission. Everything works. When I allow users to run it on server, it will try to open the auth screen on server. I need to pass the response to the web browser. 
Any ideas?
I use the auth script from the youtube api examples:

```
 # The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
  message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE,
  scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE)

storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  flags = argparser.parse_args()
  credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
  http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
```

The server side webapp is quiet simple, it allows to choose script variation and couple settings, that's all.

Comment: have the user authenticate it the first time on the web Google will return a Refresh token save the refresh token and when you are running it on the server you can use the refresh token to access the users account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are authenticating your user credentials in your server, you need to use Oauth2 (in google's case).
It took me some time understanding it in the beginning as well...
The meaning of OAuth2 is that you redirect the user to a login address provided by google, tell the service "look, after the user logged in, send the token to URL X" (your server). Your server gets some sort of token that represents the user authorizing your "app" to do stuff on his behalf.

Check out https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app

Specifically in your case - you'll need to implement the endpoint in the PHP (it needs to "listen" on an address if you get my drift)

If you don't really need user credentials and only need to access youtube API as any authenticated user, it is easier - you need to have your own credentials and do "server to server" explained here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts

Comment: My app is going to manipulate users playlists, so I suppose I need the authentication. Thanks for the answer. Think this is going to help me a lot:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app#protectauthcode